# Tom is up on the 22nd floor now

Tags: adverbs

> Tom is up on the 22nd floor now.

I am wondering about the meaning of "up". I am familiar with describing someone who lives on the 5th floor, like the under sentence.

***He is on the 5th floor.***

However in my questioned sentence, "**up**" meaning is similar to just "**on**", isn't it???

---

Furthermore, If someone lives in the 10th basement of an apartment, can I say like this?

> He is down on the 10th floor.

The reason why I am asking it is because I was able to looked using "down on the #th floor" up.
https://ludwig.guru/s/down+on+the+second+floor

Comment: Do any real apartments have 10 levels of basement?

Comment: _Up_ is not attached to the preposition _on_: it is a seprate adverb of position.

Comment: It implies that the people saying it are below him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, "up" takes on the same meaning as "on". However, this statement is likely made by someone on a lower floor, referring to Tom who is on a higher floor.

> For example, if I am on the 3rd floor, it is natural for me to say "Tom is *up* on the 22nd floor now".

So, it is fine to say "He is down on the 10th floor" **if you are on a higher floor than the 10th**.

> For example, if you are on the 25th floor, you could say "He is down on the 10th floor".

For "on", it does not matter which floor you are currently on and can be used in both cases described above.

Comment: Oh Hi user86610. However what does bracketed [h] mean? :) If you don’t mind could you tell me the meaning of [h]?

Comment: It was because I changed the capital letter H you used to a small letter h to fit in my sentence. See https://writingcommons.org/article/inserting-or-altering-words-in-a-direct-quotation/ I realised now that it was unneccessary so I have updated my answer to remove it.